# Google Cloud Spanner Slow ( over 800 ms ) connection even using cache pool

Tags: php, google-cloud-spanner

my company is thinking about migrating our databases to cloud spanner within a multi-tenant architecture, however after the first tests we have done, we are afraid of the performance we are getting.

Any ideas to improve the code below? are we doing something wrong?

```
        $cache = new SysVCacheItemPool();
        $sessionPool = new CacheSessionPool(
            $cache, [
                'minSessions' => 10,
                'maxSessions' => 10
            ]
        );
        $client = new SpannerClient([
            'projectId' => 'XXX'
            'keyFilePath' => __DIR__ . '/../config/CloudSpanner/XXX.json',
            'authCache' => $cache
        ]);
        $instance = $client->instance('XXX');
        $database = $instance->database('XXX', [ 'sessionPool' => $sessionPool ]);
        $results = $database->execute('SELECT "Hello World" as test')

        foreach ($results as $row) {
          print($row['test'] . PHP_EOL);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that come to mind, which could be increasing the latency of your operations.

#### Spanner Configuration

Does the instance you are testing on have any other load? You can check that in the monitoring tab of your Spanner instance. Make sure the CPU is not over 65% for a single region instance configuration (https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/cpu-utilization#recommended-max). I think this might not be related to your problem, since you are just testing it out, but I thought it was worth mentioning it.

#### Client Location

Are you executing the code in your local machine instead of in the GCP environment? This could significantly contribute to the latency you are seeing, especially if your Spanner server in within a region that is far away from your client. Make sure that you try to bring those two as close as possible. I would also test your code by deploying it in the GCP infrastructure, this way you could compare the latencies you are observing and rule out network related problems.

#### Sessions

I see you have configured your session pool to have a min and max of 10 sessions. This means that you can have, at max, 10 transactions being executed at the same time. If you are benchmarking multiple operations, please make sure you configure the session pool to adhere to your needs. Other than that, we usually recommend a ballpark of at most 100 session per gRPC channel, so you might have to increase this number as well. Note that I would not bump these numbers up at first, because there is a cost associated with maintaining a session pool which will increase as more sessions are added. I would try the other things mentioned beforehand.

#### Performance Measurement

Just out of curiosity, where exactly are you measuring performance? Is it from the client creation to the end of query execution? Or are you measuring only the query execution?
If possible you could create the client only once and re-use it for all of your queries.

Comment: Yeah, i am testing on my local machine, so if i am not using the GCP to deploy my applications i will have this response time? i am measuring from the client creation to the end of query execution, using the AB benchmark tool, but i tried it out, and the response times increases drastically once i iterate the results only, if i never iterate it, i get around 100ms.

Comment: You are definitely going to get better response times if you are closer to your Spanner instance. Did you create your Spanner instance in a region close to your local machine? Regarding benchmarking, you could create the client once with a session pool size that is close to how many requests you'd like to execute and measure the  execution vs the client creation separately. If your execution times increases as you iterate, it sounds to me as you are having some kind of resource contention. Maybe high CPU on your Spanner instance or your session pool is too small.